# How to seperate UnitTests for Controller Actions from Components in CakePHP 3

Tags: phpunit, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2 it was possible to Mock a Controller like this: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#a-more-complex-example
and test the action like

```
$this->testAction('/posts/add', array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'return' => 'contents'
    ));
```

In CakePHP 3 official documentation its suggested to put a valid user into the session to call an action.

BUT this makes it very hard to maintain the test. For example if the concept of User-Access-Management changes the "Articles->add" Test fails and I have to change the test.

So what I want is to write a Unit or Functional Test for a Controller-Action.
My idea was to mock the Controller->isAuthorized() method to return always true, but could not figure out how to implement it and still be able to call the action I want to test.

What is a good way of doing this?

Comment: Is that really a concern? I mean, how often do you expect to change the way your app authenticates/authorizes users? I'd think that's one of the parts of an application that will only very rarely change.

Comment: Well, it's more like, I don't know jet how this will look like. I write the tests for a test driven development - I will (mostly) not implement it. In general I think (from a UnitTest perspective) its a good idea to test Controller funtionality independent from user access rights. Just because the test for an editor editing an article fails doesn't mean that the edit action is broken. So its much harder to figure out where the error with with more independent tests...